# Pagination in NextJS with Apollo

Tags: pagination, graphql, next.js, apollo-client, apollo-server

I had implemented Pagination in Nextjs.
but I think It is not good method.
I implemented Pagination with JS slice method..

Is it bad to implement Pagination like that?

I'm using `apollo client + apollo-server + mongodb(to save blog posts)+ graphql` stack

I knew that other people did not implement Pagination like this way..

let me know Is is okay to implement like this way and If not so , Plz tell me right way to implement Pagination.

/components/pagination.tsx

```
import React from 'react';



interface PaginationProps {
    postsPerPage: number
    totalPosts: number
    paginate: (n: number) => void
}

const Pagination : React.FC<any> = ({ postsPerPage, totalPosts, paginate } : PaginationProps) => {
    const pageNumbers : number[] = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= Math.ceil(totalPosts/postsPerPage); i++) {
        pageNumbers.push(i);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <nav>
                <ul className="bg-purple-400 float-left mt-4 mb-4 text-center rounded-md text-white p-px">
                    {pageNumbers.map(number => (
                        <li key={number} className="inline-block text-base font-semibold rounded-md p-1 w-6 hover:bg-purple-500">
                            <span onClick={() => paginate(number)} className="text-white">
                                {number}
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Pagination
```

/pages/index.tsx

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import client from "../apollo-client";
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from "next/head";
import {GET_ALL_POSTS} from "../lib/query";
import {useState} from "react";
import Pagination from "../components/pagination";


export async function getStaticProps() {
    const { data } = await client.query({
        query: GET_ALL_POSTS

    })
    return {
        props : {
            posts: data.posts
        },
        revalidate: 10
    }
}

const Home: NextPage = ({posts} : any) => {
    // Pagination
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [postsPerPage] = useState(10)
    const lastIndex = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const firstIndex = lastIndex - postsPerPage;
    
    const currentPosts = (tmp : object[]) => {
        let currentPosts : object[] = [];
        currentPosts = tmp.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
        return currentPosts;
    }

    return (
      <div>
          <Head>
              <title>...</title>
             
          </Head>
          <h1 className="text-gray-550 dark:text-white">전체 글({posts.length})</h1>

              <div className="flex items-center flex-col justify-center list-none">
                  {currentPosts(posts).map((post : any, index : any) => (
                      <Link href={`/posts/${post._id}`} key={index}>
                          <a className="group container mt-5 p-4 border-b-2">
                              <h3 className="text-black text-xl dark:text-white mt-4 group-hover:text-purple-500">{post.title}</h3>
                              <p className="text-black dark:text-white mb-4">{renderDate(post.createdAt)}</p>
                              {renderTags(post.tags)}
                          </a>
                      </Link>
                  ))}
                  <Pagination postsPerPage={postsPerPage} totalPosts={posts.length} paginate={setCurrentPage}/>
              </div>
      </div>


  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically now you are fetching all posts upfront and dynamically compute the amount of pages needed for them. Depending on the number of posts, this could be a huge chunk of data, which the user probably does not need.

It would be better to fetch the data incrementally, when the user needs it. *Apollo* has a *Pagination* [api](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/overview/) which can help you with that. From the docs:

> There are many different pagination strategies a server can use for a particular list field: offset-based, cursor-based, page-number-based, forwards, backwards, and so on. Each strategy requires a slightly different set of arguments. Because these strategies can each be useful in different situations, neither Apollo nor the GraphQL specification prescribes a canonical pagination strategy.

The best advice I can give you is to work through the docs and find the one approach you deem best for your situation. What you will make heavy use of, is the `fetchMore` [function](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/core-api/#the-fetchmore-function), which allows you to fetch more posts when the user has interacted with your site. This has the positive side effect that you probably won't need the `revalidate` call every 10 seconds. You could move the query to the `Pagination` component and fetch there the amount of posts you want to display on one page.

Comment: I implemented this. but it need loading.. is it possible to prefetch data with pagination? (fetchMore)

Comment: Yes, you could prefetch the first few posts via `getStaticProps`. So basically what you did before, but only fetching a few posts, not all.

Comment: So prefetched using `getStaticProps` like limit : 10 ? (mongodb or graphql)
and `fetchMore` rest of them?

Comment: I guess better pass the first 10 posts as a variable called `initialProps` and then start fetching on the client starting page 2. The reason is that I don't think that you can pass `fetchMore` through `getStaticProps` easily (as I guess it will be serialized). I think this way is easier.